# Passing variable to cursor

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm facing problems in passing a for loop variable to an explicitly declared cursor. Here's the PL/SQL code:

```
    DECLARE

count_total number := 0;

i           number :=0;

ch          varchar(10) := 'abc';

ch2         varchar(10) := 'xyz';


CURSOR cursor_sim_b IS **--identifying if value is garbage--**
select a1,a2, a3, a4, a5, a6,
trim(translate(a1,'0123456789',' ')),
trim(translate(a2,'0123456789',' ')),
trim(translate(a3,'0123456789',' ')),
trim(translate(a4,'0123456789',' ')),
trim(translate(a5,'0123456789',' ')),
trim(translate(a6,'0123456789',' '))
from  temp_clean;

sim_b_rec cursor_sim_b%rowtype;

BEGIN

dbms_output.put_line('OUTSIDE the CURSOR ');

FOR sim_b_rec IN cursor_sim_b

LOOP

dbms_output.put_line('OUTSIDE the FOR LOOP ');

FOR i IN 1..6
LOOP
ch := 'a' ||i;

if sim_b_rec.ch is not null  **--ERROR--**

then
BEGIN

execute immediate 'update temp_clean
set sim_b_rec.%ch = NULL';

EXCEPTION

 WHEN  OTHERS THEN

   ROLLBACK;

END;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('a'||i||'<' || ch || '>');

end if;
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Getting the following error:
PLS-00302: component 'CH' must be declared

**Is there any way to pass the variable to the cursor?**

Comment: There is no 'ch' element in the sim_b_rec record.

Comment: @Gary_W could you please elaborate?

Comment: This line:   if sim_b_rec.ch is not null . There's no "ch" in the cursor definition.

Comment: @Gary_W That's my question. I have declared a variable 'ch' and i want to pass it to the cursor as for every loop it will store a different value i.e a1, a2, a3 and so on. So the cursor can update the values as sim_b_rec.a1, sim_b_rec.a2 

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

`update temp_clean
set a1=case when trim(translate(a1,'0123456789',' ')) is not null then null else a1 end,
    a2=case when trim(translate(a2,'0123456789',' ')) is not null then null else a1 end,
    a3=case when trim(translate(a3,'0123456789',' ')) is not null then null else a1 end,
    a4=case when trim(translate(a4,'0123456789',' ')) is not null then null else a1 end,
    a5=case when trim(translate(a5,'0123456789',' ')) is not null then null else a1 end,
    a6=case when trim(translate(a6,'0123456789',' ')) is not null then null else a1 end`

Comment: Tried to edit my answer as obviously the statement should read:

Comment: This update statement's absolutely fine. But I want to use it in a loop as my table contains millions of records. So is there any way to pass an explicitly declared variable to a cursor?

Comment: Why does having millions of records mean you need to loop?  Row by row processing for millions of records is going to be so slow!  Perhaps I don't quite understand what else you are trying to achieve here.